# Removing repetitions of same numbers in an array

Tags: c, arrays

Task is to display the array that has no repetitions based on some user generated input.

I'm trying to compare the number with every number before it, if the equality happens, a=1, it should skip it. Code doesn't return anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int X[30],Y[30],i,j,k=0,a,N;
    printf("Length of the vector: ");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    printf("Input the numbers: ");
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        scanf("%d",X+i);
    Y[0]=X[0];
    for(i=1;i<N;i++){
        for(j=i-1;j>=0;j--)
            if(X[i]=X[j])
                a=1;
        if(a==0){
            k++;
            Y[k]=X[i];
        }
        a=0;
    }
    for(i=0;i<k;i++)
        printf("%d",Y[i]);
}
```

Comment: FYI, what you're using are `C` arrays, not vectors. `vector` is usually used to describe automatically expanding indexable sequences (that is, array-like things that can be resized live), specifically `C++`'s `std::vector`.

Comment: The word you're looking for is "array".  There is a related thing called a "vector", but C does not have them, at least not built in.  Tags edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three separate issues in your code block:

1. `a` is not initialized the first time through your loop. Add a line `a  = 0;` above your loop.
2. Your if block reads `if(X[i]=X[j])`; it should be `if(X[i] == X[j])` (you're missing one `=`)
3. Your final value of `k` is going to be one less than the total number of elements that you have. Change your final `for` loop to `i = 0; i <= k; i++`